# Symfony AWS S3 - Change signature_version

Tags: amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-s3

i use aws S3 bucket with Symfony 3.4 and when i send file i have this error :

```
Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4.
```

I think i need change 'signature_version' to v4 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_configuration.html#signature-version

But i don't know how

config.yml:

```
aws:
  version: 'lastest'
  region: 'eu-west-3'
  credentials: false
  Sqs:
    credentials: "@a_service"
```

sendFile.php

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
public function __construct(S3Client $s3Client){
  $this->s3Client = $s3Client;
}

public function sendFile($dataBase64){
  $this->s3Client->putObject([
       'Bucket' => $monbucket,
       'Key' => $key,
       'Body' => $dataBase64,
       'ACL' => 'public-read'
     ]);
}
```

> Bundle version: "aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony": "^2.0",